# Javascript set checkbox checked value to false

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I'm having an issue with Javascript. I'm trying to limit the number of checked checkbox to 5. I have a Javascript script that shows me the alert I ask to show but the still put the checkbox on checked.

To do so I'm using this Javascript script:

```
function change(_this) {
   if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 5) {
      alert("allowed only 5");
      this.checked = false;
   }
}
```

I've tried also

```
$(this).prop('checked', false);
```

And my checkboxes are the classical one

```
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name1" onchange="change(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name2" onchange="change(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name3" onchange="change(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name4" onchange="change(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name5" onchange="change(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name6" onchange="change(this)">
```

What can cause this issue?

Comment: Use the `onClick` event instead

Comment: The function argument is `_this` not `this`. So make `this.checked = false;` this `_this.checked = false;`

Comment: Since you are using jQuery anyway, it'd be simpler and cleaner to set up the event handler in jQuery as a delegated handler from the body or document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in `_this` to the change function, but then use `this.checked`, rather than `_this.checked`. In this context, `this` won't be referring to the element.

```js
function change(_this) {
   if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 5) {
      alert("allowed only 5");
      _this.checked = false;
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name1" onchange="change(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name2" onchange="change(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name3" onchange="change(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name4" onchange="change(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name5" onchange="change(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="memberName" value="Name6" onchange="change(this)">
```

Comment: Which I noted above in the comments which means this question should be closed due to a typo. No need to answer it

Comment: I probably started replying and constructing my runnable example before you commented. Ah, I didn't know the typos rule. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo